How is the matrix of a transformation represented when performing change of basis on both the input and output basis?
In the linalg book I'm reading by Gilbert Strang, this popped up: 
The sentence "If you change both bases in the same way, the new matrix is $M^{-1}AM$" is confusing me. In general, I understand the purpose of $M^{-1}AM$ as being interpreted as:

Let A be the corresponding matrix of some linear transformation T

Let M be the change-of-basis matrix from some input to some output basis

Let $M^{-1}$ be the change-of-basis matrix from the output basis to the input basis


Then $M^{-1}AM$ now represents the same transformation but having undergone a change of basis wherein we would take a vector in the input space, make it undergo a change-of-basis transformation, apply the original transformation A, then apply the inverse change-of-basis transformation to go back to the original system.
However, I'm having some sort of disconnect between the understanding above ^ and my understanding of this portion where Strang says:
"When you change the basis for V, the matrix changes from $A$ to $AM$. Because V is the input space, the matrix $M$ goes on the right. When you change the basis for $W$, the new matrix is $M^{-1}A$. We are working with the output space so M^{-1} goes on the left."
goes like:

we have changed the input basis V in $R^{n}$ to some other basis. Call the corresponding change-of-basis matrix $M_v$; thus, the transformation A, when applied to the input space should now be, $AM$.

we have also changed the output basis W in $R^m$ to some other basis. Call the corresponding change-of-basis matrix $M_w$; thus, the full transformation between input and output space should now be represented by $M_wAM_v$. I though this could be interpreted as $AM_v$ maps the change-of-basis'd input space then $M_w$ would correspondingly reconfigure the output vectors via the appropriate change-of-basis on the output space.


In a sense, I thought this would be paralleling the same sentiments of how A originally represents some transformation between input space V and output space W as something like this:
$V --> A(v) --> W$
wherein it seems like this form of $WAV$ is actually now taking the form of $IAI = A$? wherein we treat the input space of V and W as having undergone a change-of-basis to themselves, i.e.,

$V = VM_v --> M_v = I$
$W = WM_w --> M_w = I$?

I suppose it's really that snippet "if you change both bases in the same way...", then seemingly we have $AM$ and $M^{-1}A$ that's confusing me.

$M^{-1}AM$ is the matrix representation of $A$ when the basis for $V$ is $M$ and the basis for $W$ is $M$. The author's words are confusing, but the last two sentences confirm this interpretation.

@Kakashi I see. I understand that the input basis and output basis were meant to be the same. However, I'm still unsure as to why $M^{-1}$ pops up on the left-hand side. From the way the author wrote it, it seems as if they are saying that the input basis and the output basis are both undergoing the same change-of-basis. By that logic, if the change of basis on V produced M. Then , if V = W , shouldn't the same change of basis on W also produce M such that M is on the left-hand side of A? I'm curious if I'm just misunderstanding if it's actually a change of basis on both V and W, or just V.

I think about it like this: the matrix representation of $A$ in coordinates $B_1$ for $V$ and $B_2$ for $W$ should take in the coordinate representation of vector $x$ in $B_1$ and return the coordinate representation of $Ax$ in $B_2$. This matrix is none other than $B_2^{-1}AB_1$.

Is it that when we say change of basis, we only ever mean change of basis on the input space since the transformation inherently links it to the basis of some output space? Does it make sense to say we have a change of basis on the input space V, then V undergoes change of basis represented by M, then the resulting vectors $AM$ are sent through another change-of-basis matrix that isn't $M^{-1}$. Is it that the output space W must undergo some change-of-basis such that the corresponding change-of-basis matrix is $M^{-1}$? or said another way:

$V = WM_v \implies M_v = W^{-1}V$, then
$W = VM_v \implies M_w = V^{-1}W \implies M_w = M_v^{-1}$?

@Kakashi ohhhh. I see what you mean now. That was a very insightful and elucidating comment. Am I correct in interpreting what you said as $AB_1$ gives us the output vectors (corresponding coordinates) in the output space W; however, the output vector given by $AB_1v$ has not yet undergone the appropriate change-of-basis applied to W , aka is has not yet been transformed by $B_2$. But, we cannot just say then that the appropriate vector would then be $B_2AB_1v$? I'm now trying to parse out why it must be $B_2^{-1}$.

You start with $c$, the coordinates of $x$ in basis $B_1$. Then $x = B_1c$, so $Ax = AB_1c$. Then to get coordinates of $Ax$ in basis $B_2$, you multiply by $B_2^{-1}$ to get $B_2^{-1}Ax = B_2^{-1}AB_1c$. Algebraically this works because $B_1c = c_1B_{\cdot, 1} + \dots + c_n B_{\cdot, n}$

@Kakashi oh okay I think I understand now. I think I was misunderstanding what was exactly was being accomplished with the $M^{-1}AM$ that the author arrives to, but they are essentially trying to say that this is the change-of-basis of a transformation into another basis? would this process here be equivalent to what you said? Let the matrix A associate a transformation between input basis $V_1$ and output basis $W_1$. Let the matrix B associate a transformation between input basis $V_2$ and output basis $W_2$. Let $M_1$ be the change-of-basis matrix from $V_1$ to $V_2$ and let $M_2$ be the

change of basis matrix from $W_1$ to $W_2$. Furthermore, let $v_a$ be some vector associated with the coordinate space of A, i.e., residing within the transformation mapping $V_1$ to $W_1$. Similarly, let $v_b$ be some vector associated within the coordinate space of B associated with the transformation mapping $V_2$ to $W_2$. Then, $M_1v_a$ gives us a vector in $V_2$; then $BM_1v_a$ gives us the transformation of B applied to the equivalent vector from A to B; then $M_2^{-1}BM_1v_a$ sends the vector back to the morphology of A. I.E., M_2^{-1}BM_1v_a$ is the corresponding C.O.B. matrix of

B to A. Initially, I was a bit confused as to why the matrix transformations couldn't be transcribed in the same manner of how the change-of-basis is done for the input vectors. Before, I always wrapped the vectors of an input basis as always being wrapped in a matrix with linearly independent columns. However, it seems like this transcription process isn't the same between change-of-basis between basis vectors and trying to perform change-of-basis on a matrix? I thought every matrix is inherently representative of some transformation? Also, I probably did not use the word morphology right.

This is how I think about these things. It is a bit notation-heavy to write down, but I think it illuminates what you're seeing quite clearly.
We start with an abstract linear operator $A: V \to V$. In the example we have $V = \mathbb{R}^n$ but that's unimportant, except for the fact that we have a standard basis $e = (e_1, \ldots, e_n)$. What you actually write down is the matrix for $A$ with respect to this basis, which I will notate as $[^{e} A ^e] \in \operatorname{Mat}_{n, n}(\mathbb{R})$.
Now somebody tells you about a new basis $f = (f_1, \ldots, f_n)$ of $V$. The abstract linear operator $A: V \to V$ has not changed at all - it exists independently of the bases $e$ and $f$. However, if you only know $[^e A ^e]$ and $e$ and $f$, how can you write down the matrix $[^f A ^f]$ which expresses $A$ in this new basis?

This funny notation I'm using satisfies the following rule. If I have an operator $S: U \to V$ and another $T: V \to W$, and I have ordered bases $u$, $v$, $w$ of $U$, $V$, and $W$ respectively, then
$$ [^w T^v][^v S ^u] = [^w T \circ S ^u],$$
i.e. multiplication of matrices respects operator composition. From this you can prove that whenever $A: V \to V$ is an operator and $v = (v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ is any basis, matrix inverse and identity act as you would expect.
$$ [^v A ^v]^{-1} = [^v A^{-1} {^v}] \quad \text{and} \quad [^v \operatorname{id}_V ^v] = I_n.$$
How do you actually write down the matrix $[^v S ^u]$ for example? It is defined by the equations
$$ S u_j = \sum_i [^v S ^u]_{i, j} v_i.$$

Now let's come back to the original problem: we want to get $[^f A ^f]$ in terms of $[^e A ^e]$, so we can write:
$$ [^f A ^f] = [^f \operatorname{id}_V \circ A \circ \operatorname{id}_V ^f] = [^f \operatorname{id}_V ^e][^e A ^e][^e \operatorname{id}_V ^f],$$
so now you just need to know how to write down $[^e \operatorname{id}_V ^f]$ (the other matrix $[^f \operatorname{id}_V ^e]$ will be its inverse). If you look at the definition above, you'll see that if I already know how to express the vectors $f$ in the basis $e$, then $[^e \operatorname{id}_V ^f]$ will simply be the matrix of column vectors of $f$.

I see. This is very enlightening and useful notation. I think I understand about 90% of it right now and am looking over the last bit. when you say $^{e}id_{V}^f$ will simply be the matrix of the column vectors of $f$, is this akin to the statement:
"convert V via change-of-basis to be in terms of I" is the same as
$T(V) = V = IM_v \implies M_v = V$ where T is the identity transformation?
or would that be more akin to the $^{v}id_V^v = I_n$. does that mean $^{e}id_V^f$ is some rectangular identity? Then, $^{f}id_V^e$ is also some rectangular identity?

Suppose I have $e = (e_1, e_2)$ the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f = (f_1, f_2)$ the basis with $f_1 = (1, 1)$ and $f_2 = (2, -2)$. Now look at the defining equations for $[^e \operatorname{id}_V ^f]$, which say $\operatorname{id}_V f_1 = 1 e_1 + 1 e_2$ and $\operatorname{id}_V f_2 = 2 e_1 - 2 e_2$. This tells you that $[^e \operatorname{id}_V ^f] = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \ 1 & -2\end{pmatrix}$.

By way of analogy, consider rectangular $(x, y)$ and polar $(r, \theta)$ coordinates on the plane (even though they are nonlinear), and imagine the scale-by-two transformation. On one system it is represented by $(x, y) \mapsto (2x, 2y)$, wheras on the other it is represented by $(r, \theta) \mapsto (2r, \theta)$. This is the same transformation seen through two different lenses. Also consider the identity map taking a point to itself, but starting in polar coordinates and ending in rectangular: it looks like $(r, \theta) \mapsto (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$.

thank you for taking your time to write this detailed response! It seems I misunderstood the meaning of [$^{e}id_V^f$]. I'm going to go back through this and try to parse it and give an updated response. Thank you!
